# Create a shiny app that plots one of two plots depending on an input

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny app that will plot something if a user selects one input and plots something entirely different if the user selects something else. Below is a very basic reproduction of what I am trying to do:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(selectInput("thisthat", "This or that?", c("This", "That"))),
  fluidRow(column(3,plotOutput("plot")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    observeEvent(input$thisthat, {
      if (input$thisthat == "This"){
        
        plot(mtcars$hp, mtcars$mpg)
        
      } else if(input$thisthat == "That"){
        
        plot(mtcars$disp, mtcars$drat)
        
      }
    })
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The outcome is that I should see a plot of HP vs MPG in mtcars if the user selects "This", and I should see a plot of disp vs drat in mtcars if the user selects "That". This app does create plots, but it dumps them into RStudio rather than displaying them directly in the app. I need the app to show the plots.

How do I get my app to do that?

Comment: Try with removing the unnecessary `observeEvent`.

Comment: That worked, thank you!